# Instagram Api (https://api.instagram.com/oauth/access_token" , "post" , parameters) returns 400 Bad Request

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, instagram-api

I am developing an app using `instagram api` to bring feed to my website. I have following code but when i try to access the access_token using the code provided by Instagram it's giving me `400 Bad request error. I would be much obliged if someone could help me to overcome this problem. Many Thanks

```
string code="";

 public ActionResult Index()
    {
       if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(Request["code"]))
       {
           code = Request["code"].ToString();
           GetDataInstagramToken();

       }  


         return View();

       }


 public ActionResult Instagram()
 {
   var client_id = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["instagram.clientid"].ToString();
   var redirect_uri = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["instagram.redirecturi"].ToString();
   string url = "https://api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize/?client_id=" + client_id + "&redirect_uri=" + redirect_uri + "&response_type=code";
    Response.Redirect(url);

    return View();

}

public void GetDataInstagramToken()

{
    var json = "";
    var page = HttpContext.CurrentHandler as Page;
    try
    {
        NameValueCollection parameters = new NameValueCollection();
        parameters.Add("client_id", ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["instagram.clientid"].ToString());
        parameters.Add("client_secret", ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["instagram.clientsecret"].ToString());
        parameters.Add("grant_type", "authorization_code");
        parameters.Add("redirect_uri", ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["instagram.redirecturi"].ToString());
        parameters.Add("code", code);

        WebClient client = new WebClient();
        var result = client.UploadValues("https://api.instagram.com/oauth/access_token", "post", parameters);
        var response = System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetString(result);

        // deserializing nested JSON string to object  
        var jsResult = (JObject)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(response);
        string accessToken = (string)jsResult["access_token"];
        int id = (int)jsResult["user"]["id"];

        //This code register id and access token to get on client side  
        page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "GetToken", "<script> var instagramaccessid=\"" + @"" + id + "" + "\"; var instagramaccesstoken=\"" + @"" + accessToken + "" + "\";</script>");




    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw;

    }
}
```

I am getting exception at 
`var result = client.UploadValues("https://api.instagram.com/oauth/access_token", "post", parameters);`

Comment: Please Check My Answer It Can help you

Answer (score 0):

In this line

```
client.UploadValues("https://api.instagram.com/oauth/access_token", "post", parameters);
```

You don't send any value to `Instagram`. If you check your parameter you can see your key but you cant see any value.

Try this:

```
 public async void GetTokenFromCode()
    {
        var values = new Dictionary<string, string>    {
          { "client_id","Your ChatId" },
          { "client_secret", "Your Client Secret" },
          { "grant_type", "authorization_code" },
          { "redirect_uri", "Your Redirect url"},
          { "code", "code" }    };
        var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(values);
        var response = await client.PostAsync("https://api.instagram.com/oauth/access_token", content);
        var responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    }
```